# Find out web traffic source by the referrer header

Tags: python, http-headers

I've honestly tried to find libraries (in Python) which would allow me to easily do this. Or to find some precise instructions how to parse the referrer header properly. But nothing so far.
Any ideas? Need to do this myself on the backed, not by importing data from Google Analytics or something. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Flask API. The "request" object has a bounch of important information, such as the IP.
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/

You can you external services to check the location based in the IP, such as https://ipstack.com/.

Another, more complete option is using Google Analytics:
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/
You just add a tag to you HTML and Google does the rest!

Comment: Yeah, I have access to the header itself (I use Django on this project though). Sure I'm aware about google analytics:) I just need this data on the backend, not just to see it in the GA dashboard. Is there any way to download it from GA?

Comment: Not that I know of... But i have done BI projects by means of Django by creating a middleware for logging and analysis of all request. I highly suggest this architecture since it is very clean and reliable. Geolocation is only one example of what you can post to your backend server. check is out:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp